# How to delete a data in database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, gridview, datatable

I have this form that takes these information from user `@ID, @From, @To, @Title, @Message`. Then it insert them into a database table.

How can I delete a certain data using the `@ID`? User will have a `dataGridView1` with all the `datatable`, then by getting the `CurrentCell` it will delete this certain data.

```
private void delet_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

    string strid = dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString();
    //MessageBox.Show(strid);
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(strid);
           
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            
    cmd.CommandText = "Delete * from MessagesTable where [ID]=@ID ";
    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);

    MessageBox.Show("Message was deleted");
    BindGrid();
}
```

Comment: Side notes: You are missing  `using` blocks for the command and connection objects. Do not cache the connection object. `CommandType.Text` is the default. You can condense the code down to `using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE .... ", con)) {...`

Comment: Concur with charlieface. Store the connection string and use the `string,string` constructor of the command; one less thing to have to `using`. Also read https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: Then have a read of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72310602/insert-current-row-from-gridview-into-database - there is an easier way to do your database access than the pain you're currently putting yourself through. To get to a point where you can see the types of screens I've screenshotted in that answer you need to add a DataSet type of file to your project and then right click on the surface of it and choose Add Tableadapter and fill in your connection details

Comment: It's the visual, less manual version of @user18387401's answer, which I wholly concur with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

```
private void delet_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            int i = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
              string strid = dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString();
                //MessageBox.Show(strid);
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(strid);
               
    
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                
                cmd.CommandText = "Delete from MessagesTable where [ID]=@ID ";
            
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Message was deleted");
                BindGrid();
              
      }
```

Comment: it gives me this error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '*'.'

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "Delete from MessagesTable where [ID]=@ID ";

Comment: okay i removed the '*' and it worked Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are almost certainly going about this all wrong. You should start with a `DataTable`. If appropriate, you can query the database to populate it by calling `Fill` on a data adapter. You can then bind the table to your `DataGridView` via a `BindingSource`, which you would add in the designer, e.g.

```cs
var table = new DataTable();

using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SQL query here", "connection string here"))
{
    adapter.Fill(table);
}

BindingSource1.DataSource = table;
DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1;
```

You then mark the current row as deleted by calling `RemoveCurrent` on the `BindingSource`. That will hide the row in the grid but it won't affect the database at that stage. To save the changes to the database, you call `Update` on an appropriately configured data adapter, which may be the same one you called `Fill` on in the first place. You could call `Update` to save the change as soon as the user deletes the row or you could just cache all changes locally - inserts, updates and deletes - and then call `Update` once at the end to save all the changes together.

Comment: By "appropriately configured" user18.. probably means "use an [SqlCommandBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) to generate some insert, update and delete queries for you rather than pecking them out by hand". Then when you get tired of plumbing that in by hand as well as your data binding etc, check out the options for getting VS to do it for you in the link I posted on the question

Comment: @CaiusJard, I'm not necessarily a fan of command builders myself, but they do make things easier in supported scenarios. I simply meant that the data adaoter should have an appropriate `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` as required, however they are created.